# Multiple checkbox select in MVC C#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have table like showed below. I want to check/uncheck (for now just trying out check) values in the table based on the type I select. Could this be done somehow like this? Or do I somehow need to send request from javascript to see updated values? Or could this be done by using C# only?

```html
var list = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@table);
            <form asp-controller="Consumer" asp-action="" method="post">
                <div class="row justify-content-end" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
                    @foreach (var type in ObjectTypes.All)
                    {
                        <label style="margin-right: 10px;">
                            <input onclick="selectType(@list, @type)" style="margin-right: 5px;" type="checkbox" id="@type" name="type" value="@type">@type
                        </label>
                    }
                </div>
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Object Id</th>
                        <th>Object type</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @if (table.Count > 0)
                    {
                        @for (int i = 0; i < table.Count; i++)
                        {
                            <input type="hidden" name="@("items[" + i + "].ObjectId")" value="@table[i].ObjectId"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="@("items[" + i + "].ObjectType")" value="@table[i].ObjectType"/>
                            <tr>
                                <td>@(++id)</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="@("items[" + i + "].Checked")" type="checkbox" value="true" @(table[i].Checked ? "checked" : " ")/>
                                </td>
                                <td>@table[i].ObjectId</td>
                                <td>@table[i].ObjectType</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
```

I had such js function:

```
function selectType(items, type)
{
   return items.filter(x => x.ObjectType === type).map(x => x.Checked = true);
}
```

But I need to add `checked` attribute to the checkbox input and I have no idea how that should be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp), I can see you are able to switch the "checked attribute" using:

```
document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = true;
```

But I do not get the reason why you want to return something in your `selectType` method. It is the method called when you will click on a checkbox, so you do not need to return anything. You will just need to change the Checked attribute for this tag. Something like that should do the trick:

```
function selectType(items, type)
{
   document.getElementById(type).checked = true; // I assume type is the Id of the element
}
```

Comment: Type is not id of checkboxes I want to select :( I want to select checkboxes from                                     `<input name="@("items[" + i + "].Checked")" type="checkbox" value="true" @(table[i].Checked ? "checked" : " ")/>` if type of item is selected above

Comment: Maybe you can try to use `getElementsByName()`.